# Как вывести только 1 нужное значение?

Tags: php

Делаю парсер цен с сайта. Уже задавал вопрос, мне подсказали. Но тот код который мне подсказали, выдает сразу все значения. А мне нужно что бы я мог работать с 1 нужным значением, а так же что бы все значения были в МАССИВЕ.

Вот код:

```
<?php

set_time_limit(300);

$urljson = file_get_contents("http://loot.farm/fullprice.json");
$data = json_decode($urljson);
foreach($data as $obj)
    {
    echo $obj->price.'<br>';
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так?

```
foreach($data as $obj)
{
  echo $obj->price . '<br>';
  break;
}
```

А лучше вообще так:

```
echo $data[0]->price . '<br>';
```

Comment: СПС. Я чет протупил:)

Comment: @6o6ep, если помогло, прими ответ нажатием на галочку слева от него.

Comment: ну уж если два варианта предложили - давайте тогда и классический однострочный еще) `json_decode(file_get_contents("http://loot.farm/fullprice.json"))[0]->price;`

Comment: @Qwertiy, вообще, по-хорошему, надо бы еще ошибки обрабатывать (это модно). Но тут ошибке неоткуда взяться. Значит надо самим сгенерировать! Вариант с обработкой ошибки: `try {
    foreach ($data as $obj) {
        throw new Exception($obj->price);
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage().'<br>';
}`

Answer (score 1):

А зачем юзать цикл для одного значения?

```
set_time_limit(300);
$content = file_get_contents('http://loot.farm/fullprice.json');
// Сохранить всё в массив
$array = json_decode($content, 1);

// Вывести нужное без цикла
echo $array[0]['price'];
```